# TYPO3 V10 textmedia element: How to change the directory of the virtual video file in fileadmin?

Tags: video, typo3

When embedding youtube videos with the textmedia element, TYPO3 generates a virtual file in user_upload `the_title_of_the_video.youtube`. Is it possible to configure the directory where this file is stored?

Comment: IMO, there's no such core functionality. But maybe this package can help: https://github.com/beechit/default_upload_folder

Comment: You could add the Youtube-Video-Element directly via the FileList. There you can control the Folder it is uploaded to.